# How can I add a second title to my thesis?

Tags: titles, overleaf, thesis

I am doing my thesis and I need to have two cover pages, one with the title in English and another with the title in Spanish. I am using a template and I am using this code.

```
% Variables for the title page in displayed order
\providecommand{\theinstitute}{University of Barcelona}


\providecommand{\thetitlelabel}{Topic:}
\providecommand{\thetitle}{Shocks and Frictions in the Spanish economy}
\providecommand{\thesubtitle}{A DSGE model}

\providecommand{\theauthorlabel}{By:}
\providecommand{\theauthor}{Name}
\providecommand{\theauthoridlabel}{ID}
\providecommand{\theauthorid}{xxxxxxxxx}
\providecommand{\theauthoremail}{\url{mail}}

\providecommand{\theadvisorlabel}{Advisor:}
\providecommand{\theadvisor}{Professor...}
\providecommand{\thecity}{city}

% leave empty for actual compilation of images, use "draft" for faster compilation while in draft state
\providecommand{\thedraft}{draft}

\maketitle
```

The thing is that I need the same in Spanish so I guess I need to create something like:

```
\makespanishtitle
```

but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Heavily depends on your document class. Can you provide a minimum working example? A few lines of code, as short as possible, that one can copy and paste to overleaf?

Assuming you use the `scrartcl` class, you simply call all relevant macros again like this:

```
  \documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}

  \begin{document}
  % Make english title
  \title{English Title}
  \subtitle{Hello World}
  \maketitle

  % Make spanish title
  \title{Título español}
  \subtitle{Hola Mundo}
  \maketitle

  The Text
  \end{document}
```

Comment: So far I have the following: br/ `include{config/config}
\begin{document} 
\include{src/preamble}` br/ the document 'config' has `\input{config/variables}`where variables is the code I have written in the question. I am trying to `\input{config/titlespanish}`but is not showing. br/ finally the section 'preamble' have the following: br/ `% Titlepage

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage\null\newpage

\input{sections/abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\input{config/title_catalan}


% Tables of contents
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents`

Comment: Hard to tell what seems to be the problem here, as I do not know, what's in you included source files.
Have you tried the snippet provided in the answer?